# Is it possible to implement step-up authentication using AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am experimenting with *AWS Amplify* -and the whole AWS infrastructure- to figure out if it supports a specific workflow I need to implement for a client.

The idea is to have a user authenticate (using Cognito User Pools, not federated/openId logins) with email/password and **only** require a step-up with MFA when the user needs to access sensitive information or tooling (similar to how this [Auth0 guide](https://auth0.com/docs/mfa/step-up-authentication) explains it).

**In other words:** I do not want to always require users to confirm their signin, right away after they signed in. Most sessions (where a user should be able to read/update data!) will not require this at all. Only some actions require the user to supply MFA verification for their account.

It is important to note that I **need** to be able to interact with (for example) DynamoDB in both situations (confirmed signin, unconfirmed signin) and other parts of AWS.

Is it possible to implement this? Perhaps using AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not available as a configuration option on AWS amplify as of today.

The way I would implement it, is a Cognito Custom Authentication Flow. I did not test this set of high level instructions - bear with me if I missed something.

**Scenario 1** : regular authentication : just leverage Amplify Auth and Cognito password based authentication.

**Scenario 2** : at some point in the customer journey, your application needs a higher level of authentication.

At this stage, the client app would trigger a custom authentication flow. This involves switching authentication flow (as described here https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/switch-auth/q/platform/js) and potentially having multiple flow in `awsconfigure.json` file

Once switched, your client app can trigger a second Auth flow (a custom one) as described here https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/switch-auth/q/platform/js#custom_auth-flow

The custom auth would request the client app to provide a valid JWT token (the one you obtained from scenario 1) and the additional OTP. This would ensure, only correctly authenticated users can submit an OTP.

To implement that flow, you'll need an AWS Lambda function. The Lambda function will implement the various phases of the challenge negotiation and also verify the credentials provided (the JWT token and the OTP). The whole process is documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-define-auth-challenge.html

Here is an example of a custom auth I implemented in Python and the corresponding client code in Swift
https://gist.github.com/sebsto/6f5d9caf60c3db40ac245c1a9bb42b87

This does not exactly implements your use case, but it should be close enough to get started.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @sébastien-stormacq! Knowing there is a way to do it already helps a lot. And as I figured, we need to dive deeper into the Lambda's to get this to work. If you permit, I have a related question: Would it be possible to still use the SMS-verification in this solution? Can we trigger AWS to send a verification code from our Lamda function?

Comment: I think this possible (I never tried it myself), either the Lambda can reply to DEFINE_AUTH_CHALLENGE_REQUEST with CHALLENGE_NAME ==  SMS_MFA (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-define-auth-challenge.html) or you can call InitiateAuth passing a SMS_MFA as challenge name (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html)

Comment: Awesome @sébastien-stormacq, that is exactly the direction I needed. Many thanks again!

Comment: @SébastienStormacq I do not believe these work, I have used our enterprise support to contact amazon about a very similar situation and they say it is not possible to mix custom auth with Cognito MFA (TOTP or SMS). They say if you need this combination (our use case was passwordless email links but using Cognito MFA) then you need to use external MFA providers. I think you are on the right track above with a custom auth flow accepting a valid access token from the other pool, but you may need to use something like Twilio Authy instead of cognito MFA to do the MFA step.

Comment: Thank you @ravenscar for the feedback. As I said, I did not implement this myself. Your comment will help me to build a prototype